# Vue 3 + Typescript : Watch model property

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to watch my Typescript model attribute and it's working but giving me a warning in the console and I cannot find how to remove it.

Here's my Typescript model :

```
import { watch, ref, Ref, reactive } from 'vue'

export default class Resa {
  public id: Number = 0
  public deferred_invoicing: Ref<Boolean> = ref(false)

  constructor(properties?: Object) {
    watch(this.deferred_invoicing, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      console.log(newValue)
    }
  }
}
```

The watch is working but I have this warning in my console `[Vue warn]: Invalid watch source:  false A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types.`

Am I doing something wrong ?

I already tried to use a string `'deferred_invoicing'` instead of `this.deferred_invoicing`

Answer (score 0):

Your class instance was made `Reactive` somewhere, making it unref `deferred_invoicing` property

Use

```
    watch(toRaw(this).deferred_invoicing, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      console.log(newValue)
    }
```